# Missing "Edit" link on closed questions

Tags: support, closed-questions, editing

Today, I wanted to try an edit a [potentially valid question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/28-triffids-later) which was asked in incorrect tone (as a rant) and was thus closed.

However, there was no "Edit" tag.

I know this is not a general rule on SE sites - I can edit closed questions on SO. I can also edit non-closed questions on SciFi SE.

Is this some special privilege to edit closed questions that I lack on SciFi due to insufficient rep? Or some SciFi SE specific rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be restrictions around suggesting edits to closed questions, but they have been lifted.

The current restrictions are:

- You cannot suggest an edit on a post if there is already a pending suggested edit on that post.
- There are no suggested edits on the meta site.
- Anonymous users (people who suggest an edit without having an account) must wait until the post is at least 10 minutes old.
- A user who has had too many suggested edits rejected may be prevented from suggesting edits for a few days.

See the [suggested edit FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work/76284#76284) for more information.

Comment: The 6-hour limit is for *anonymous* edits.

Comment: @Rebecca: Ooops, thanks for the correction. I still can't find any mention of the restriction on closed questions.

Answer (score 2):

I just realized that I don't yet have full editing privileges.

According to the FAQ:

> 1000 rep  Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits

This must be why I also don't even see the "Edit" link on *closed* questions.

Comment: It is so bizarre seeing this _now_, since Gilles's edit bumped the post...

Comment: @Izkata - why??

Comment: I had a "What the frell are you... oh, this is from over two years ago" moment  =P